# Building and installing a evothings estimote ibeacon app using cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ibeacon, estimote

I'm experimenting with estimote iBeacons and tried their running their demo app *ibeacon-scan* [1] using the EvothingsWorkbench [2] on my android smartphone, which worked: I was able to monitor the ibeacons located nearby.
Then, I tried building an android app with cordova by following their instructions [3]:

```
# create cordova project
$ cordova create monitr com.evothings.monitr monitr

# (remove all www files & copy demo app files into www dir)

# configure platforms to deploy to
$ cordova platform add android

# build android app
$ cordova build android

# install android app on smartphone
$ adb install -r platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
```

It was built and installed on my smartphone, however, when I start the app, it won't show me any ibeacon. Why?

[1] http://evothings.com/doc/examples/ibeacon-scan.html

[2] a desktop application for running apps on mobile devices, see http://evothings.com/doc/studio/workbench.html

[3] http://evothings.com/doc/build/cordova-guide.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the demo app requires the *cordova-plugin-ibeacon* plugin [1].

**Installation**

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon
```

[1] https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon